# selecting in php WHERE x = $array[index]?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I've tried searching for answers to my problem but no one else seems to have had this problem! I'm basically trying to select in php using the WHERE statement, I want to compare my $ID to variables stores in an array called $resultAddID2. This array has values [1,2,1]; if I try accessing $resultAddID2[0] it works fine, but if I try to do it with $resultAddID2[1] or $resultAddID2[2] it doesn't work at all! I'm sure this is something silly but for the life of me I just can NOT figure it out! Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Here's the part where I try to do this:

```
$resultAddID = mysql_query("SELECT ADDRESS_ID FROM hospital");

while($resultAddID1=mysql_fetch_array($resultAddID)){

$resultAddID2[]=$resultAddID1['ADDRESS_ID'];


for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
$resultAddT = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address WHERE ID = $resultAddID2[]");
$resultAddTm= mysql_fetch_array($resultAddT);
$resultAddT2[]=$resultAddTm['GOVER_ID'];

}
}
$response["hospADD"]= $resultAddT2;
```

Comment: `$resultAddID2[]` should be wrapped around `{}`'s and you might want to try: `{$resultAddID2[$i]}` AND move the `for` statement after the `while`

Comment: THANK YOU! Just changing the place of the {}'s made it work! Can you post this as an answer so I'd accept it as the correct one?

Comment: `$resultAddID2[]` in an SQL query interpolation? Seems legit... Why the `[]`?

Comment: I'm new to PHP so sometimes I tend to use unnecessary notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `{}`'s like

```
$resultAddT = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address WHERE ID = {$resultAddID2[$i]}");
```

It would be better if you did something like this because you are querying the second item too many times

```
$resultAddID = mysql_query("SELECT ADDRESS_ID FROM hospital");

while($resultAddID1=mysql_fetch_array($resultAddID)){
    $resultAddID2[]=$resultAddID1['ADDRESS_ID'];
}
for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    $resultAddT = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address WHERE ID = {$resultAddID2[$i]}");
    $resultAddTm= mysql_fetch_array($resultAddT);
    $resultAddT2[] = $resultAddTm['GOVER_ID'];

}
$response["hospADD"]= $resultAddT2;
```

OR simpler yet:

```
$resultAddID = mysql_query("SELECT ADDRESS_ID FROM hospital");
while($resultAddID1=mysql_fetch_array($resultAddID)){
    $resultAddT = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address WHERE ID = {$resultAddID1['ADDRESS_ID']}");
    $resultAddTm= mysql_fetch_array($resultAddT);
    $resultAddT2[] = $resultAddTm['GOVER_ID'];
}
$response["hospADD"]= $resultAddT;
```

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend the last example to reduce code if it works for you.